# Jazz and all that

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, music

> [image]
>
> **Across**
> 1/4/9. Isn't Satchmo sad during the final parts of Miles Davis song? (5,5,5)
> 7. Baron von Richthofen's rank above the king? (3)
> 10. Assistants have a bit of chlorine added to aqua regia and other similar substances (5)
> 11. People getting advantage as Benfica tries getting openers of Everton and Inter, losing time (13)
> 17. Sweet to take Gary to court hearing (6)
> 18. Mrs. Simpson's husband somehow awarded a cut (6)
> 20. Humble countdown to seize missing Head of Operations, Head of Navigation and Head of Engineering (3,4,2,4)
> 25. Tops of jazz returning in *Introduction to Scott Joplin* (5)
> 26. New paint for a crosser of the Atlantic (5)
> 27. Put together a wedded couple (3)
> 28. Final symbol in some games (5)
> 29. Country musician Kenny gets mixed up with strange type (5)
>
> **Down**
> 2. Everyone that is a woman (5)
> 3. Wonderful getting, at last, wife Eleanor to President Roosevelt (5)
> 5. Tour around college campus, initially rejected, beginning to take place (5)
> 6. Fashionable diet doing away with the last bit of meat, which is outside of the mainstream (5)
> 8. A bird has left the Big Ben? (5)
> 11. Standard recurrently featured in music is abysmal (5)
> 12. Dark time is almost beginning to turn (5)
> 13. Pass on for green light (5)
> 14. German car stereo's final sound (5)
> 15. Maybe Abu Bakr al-Baghdadi is life force behind militant group (5)
> 16. Grass's jagged edges (5)
> 19. One way to have breakfast shown by Biden, perhaps (2,3)
> 21. Remove weapons from a French army after taking out Sarkozy finally (5)
> 22. Declining Darth's introduction, facing dark side Force (5)
> 23. A kind of vote to make jazz music a playground staple (5)
> 24. A bit of jazz to promote rock band (2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**
Corrections and completion, thanks to [@wI](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92831/jazz-and-all-that/92842#comment266625_92842)

---

After a few hours there is no other solution, so here is my "not-quite" attempt:

> [image]
>
>  **Across**
>  1/4/9. AINT (isn't) LOUIS (Armstrong) BLUE (sad) between two S letters from mileS daviS
>  7. The Red Baron was an ACE which outranks KING in cards
>  10. Assistants - AIDS - have C (a bit of chlorine)
>  11. Anagram of BENFICA TRIES and E I initials but without T
>  17. SUE GARY (we hear)
>  18. The abdicated King - anagram of AWARDED with A removed
>  20. COUNTDOWN TO SEIZE after removing initials O, N and E
>  25. JANIS (Joplin) is JA (from jazz) + NI (in reversed) + initial S
>  26. Ship's name is anagram of PAINT
>  27. The letter A with the pair DD in wedded
>  28. Embedded in sOME GAmes
>  29. Anagram of G (singer Kenny G) and TYPE
>
>  **Down**
>  2. ALL (everyone) + IE (that is)
>  3. Wonderful - NICE with E from wifE, Eleanor was NIECE of President Roosevelt
>  5. Remove T from Tour, put OUR around initials of College Campus
>  6. Fashionable = IN + DIET without the final T
>  8. C(L)OCK is a bird with Left
>  11. Embedded backwards in "musiC IS ABysmal"
>  12. NIGH (almost) + T from to turn
>  13. FOR - GO (green light)
>  14. AUDI + last O from stereO
>  15. IRA (militants) + QI (life force)
>  16. Anagram of EDGES
>  19. Anagram of BIDEN
>  21. UN (French one) + ARMY - Y (last letter)
>  22. D from Darth + YING (as in yin ~ yang)
>  23. Play on words: a SWING vote, a music genre
>  24. Embedded in "jaZZ TO Promote"

Comment: The missing clues: 7a: ACE (ddef), 8d: CLOCK (C(L)OCK), 22d: DYING (D_ + YING), 25a: JANIS (JA_ + IN< + S_), 12d is NIGH + T_ 24d is hidden string

Comment: @wl thanks, I wondered about RED being incorrect, it didn't quite work.